# Javascript custom callback function not executing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to wait until ajax call returns and than process code so I have this code for ajax call.

```
function ajax( data, url, method, callback ) {

        $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                method: method,
                dataType: "application/json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }).always(function (data, textStatus) {
                callback();
            });
    };

vm.app.ajax({data}, "url", "post", function () {
    alert('cdndvnidvndi');
});
```

But I never receive call inside callback function. Is there something wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

I cant find anything wrong accept for the `dataType`. But this code works for me.

```js
var vm = {app:{ajax}}

function ajax(data, url, method, callback) {

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    method: method,
    dataType: "json", // change the dataType to just 'json'
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  }).always(callback); // there is no reason to wrap the callback in a function
};

vm.app.ajax({
  data: 'none'
}, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "get", function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually ajax is a function inside app Object and I am calling from another Object. Everything works fine and I can see results coming in fine but it never hits callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I am try to resolve this problem to change my code to replace callback().
in my code use echo json_encoder($data); in $data pass value which i wont in my view page  and in ajax submit form like:

```
 $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             dataType: 'json',
             url: url,
             data: 'search=' +search,
             success: function (data) { 
              alert(data);//resend data get here
              }
        });
```

use this type code use.

Comment: I understand that English is not everyone's first language here, but I really have no idea what you're saying. I honestly don't even know if this is an actual answer or just a comment.